# Running setup.py install for lxml ... error windows for requirement file

Tags: python, lxml, requirements.txt

I am trying to download through `pip install -r requirements.txt` and it downloads all the requirments but throws this error at the end
 `Running setup.py install for lxml ... error`
please help I am using **python 2.7.18**
this is the full error with top three lines showing the last working lines.

````
    Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5_5qvbii\\lxml\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5_5qvbii\\lxml\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-cb9mbztf\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\lxml'
         cwd: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5_5qvbii\lxml\
    Complete output (77 lines):
    Building lxml version 4.2.5.
    Building without Cython.
    ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

    Using build configuration of libxslt
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
    copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
    copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
    copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
    copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
    copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
    copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
    copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
    copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
    copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\html
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron
    copying src\lxml\etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
    copying src\lxml\etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
    copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
    copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml
    copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\includes
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5_5qvbii\\lxml\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5_5qvbii\\lxml\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-cb9mbztf\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\lxml' Check the logs for full command output.```
````

Answer (score 0):

The error is really self explanatory.
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
So you will need to install visual studio accordingly.

Later for compile-app usage:
You need the Visual c++ redistributable according to python version you use to compile your app.
Also the remote pc('customer pc') will need this.You can include c++ redistributable to your installer if you make one like Inoo setup.
There are quite many examples on internet.

Comment: I corrected that by installing lxml separately but now I have this error ```ImportError: No module named selenium``` any help? I have selenium installed.